# Screenshot instead of output in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I just started trying out OpenGL and I'm having a strange issue.

If I compile and execute using `g++ test.c -lGL -lGLU -lglut` then `./a.out`, a sepearate window opens (of the size specified in the code). But instead of having the output of the code in it, it has a screenshot of the screen inside it (of the portion of the screen it overlaps).

This is definitely not something to do with the code, since it's running fine on my friend's computer. But I need to fix it on my PC.

I'm on Linux Mint 15 64bit (HP DV6 6121tx).

So I'm not able to proceed further. Here's my code:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#define drawOneLine(x1,y1,x2,y2) glBegin(GL_LINES); glVertex2f ((x1),(y1)); glVertex2f ((x2),(y2)); glEnd();


void init()
{
  glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  gluOrtho2D (-600,600,-400,400);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
  glutInitWindowSize(1200,800);
  glutCreateWindow("ABCD");

  init();

  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not drawing anything, because you forgot to set glutDisplayFunc, and your drawing function does not clear backbuffer before rendering.

Comment: You are probably using a compositing window manager (e.g. Xfce), judging by the way you are describing the situation. You cannot do single-buffered drawing in such a case. Replace `GLUT_SINGLE` with `GLUT_DOUBLE` and call `glutSwapBuffers (...)` at the end of `init (...)`. This should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You've asked for a single-buffered window so you'll have to `glFlush()`/`glFinish()` to force queued output to the screen.

Add a `glFinish()` to the end of `init()`.